# Using Simple Injector as Auto-Mocking with AutoFixture

Tags: simple-injector, autofixture

Is it possible to append the `ResolveUnregisteredType` method to try and resolve any unregistered types using `AutoFixture` registered types?

Something like

```
Container.ResolveUnregisteredType += (sender, e) => {
    e.Register(new SpecimenContext(fixture).Resolve(type));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there:

```cs
Container.ResolveUnregisteredType += (sender, e) =>
{
    var instance = new SpecimenContext(fixture).Resolve(e.UnregisteredServiceType);
    e.Register(() => instance);
}
```